# recipe lines execution order while invoking function

Tags: makefile

Please suggest what rule defines that makefile

```
all:
    @echo "Line 1"
    $(info Line 2)
```

is executed so that

```
Line 2
Line 1
```

is printed. Next question is how to overcome such behaviour except of splitting into two targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make will always expand all make variables and functions in the entire recipe (all lines) before it invokes any recipe lines.  Since `$(info ...)` is a make function, it's expanded first and the expansion prints the "Line 2" you see first.  After that expansion the recipe consists of just one line which is passed to the shell for execution and shows "Line 2".

You should just use shell commands if you care about the order of things:

```
all:
        @echo "Line 1"
        @echo "Line 2"
```